# How to match either of regexes?

Tags: html, regex

I have two regular expressions:

```
selected.*(?<=value=)(['"])(.*)\1
```

and

```
(?<=value=)(['"])(.*)\1(?=.*selected)
```

Separately they work fine, but I need a regex that matches either the first one, or the secod one. The alternative sign | is of no use here.

How could I match either regex in a single one?

Inputs:

```
<option selected value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
```

and

```
<option selected value="a">a</option>
<option value="b" selected>b</option>
```

The first regex matches 'a' in the first input, the second regex matches 'b' in the second one, but when I combine two regexes with alternative sign, new regex matches nothing in both inputs.'

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using php engine

Comment: Provide some examples of input and matches.

Comment: "*The alternative sign `|` is of no use here*" - why?

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to match the values of some tags that has the attribute "selected". So I've got a slightly better alternative http://regex101.com/r/nF1fD9/1

Comment: You should better use a proper HTML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should work for both cases without using alternation i.e. `|`:

```
(?=.*?selected).*?(?<=value=)(['"])(.*?)\1
```

OR if these tags can go on to multiple lines:

```
(?=[^>]*\sselected\b)[^>]*(?<=value=)(['"])([^>]*?)\1
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hM8yY0/4)

Comment: What about `<option value="selected">`?

Comment: @Gumbo: I updated to take care of that case but as this involves some HTML tags and there can be some more edge cases as well.

Comment: @Gumbo: Easy enough to fix: `(?=.*?selected).*?(?<=value=)(['"])(?!selected\1)(.*?)\1`.

Comment: Then what about `<option value="not selected">`?

Comment: TLDR: use an html parser :)